# Getting error while sending email using Powershell 4.0

Tags: office365, powershell-4.0

Though this question was posted by multiple members and there were solutions provided but none of it worked on Powershell 4.0. Following is the error

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was  not
>   authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

I am using following snippet found through google:

```
$EmailTo = "abc@email.com"
$EmailFrom = "ced@email.com"
$Subject = "Test" 
$Body = "Test Body" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com" 
$filenameAndPath = "C:\Users\ABC\DEsktop\Text_file.txt"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("ced@email.com", "abcsd1234");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Let me know if there is an alternative to it.
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring due to the way Office 365 deals with [direct sends](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123). You can't use `smtp.office365.com` as your SMTP server. As per the documentation...

> This indicates that you are connecting to the SMTP client submission
>   endpoint (smtp.office365.com), which can't be used for direct send.
>   For direct send, use the MX endpoint for your Office 365 tenant, which
>   ends with "mail.protection.outlook.com." So, please let your admin
>   check the MX record. Moreover, please check if the SMTP port is
>   25/TLS.